# Evenly distributing n points along a line

Tags: math

I'd like to know which formula am I supposed to use in order to distribute n points along a line so they are uniformly distribute.

Note: length/2 <= n > 0

The distance between the points have to be the same, so:

For length = 10, points = 1:
----0-----

For length = 10, points = 2:
--0----0--

For length = 10, points = 3:
-0--0--0-- (Note how you always "start" by the left, if you started from the right, it'd be like this: --0--0--0-)

For length = 10, points = 5:
0-0-0-0-0-0

For length = 10, points 7:
It's not possible, 7 is bigger than length/2

Comment: Your question is too vague. Are you just placing points at integer coordinates on a horizontal line? Do you need something that works with lines in arbitrary directions, or with curved lines? Can the points be placed at non-integer coordinates? Should the space at the end of a line equal half the space between adjacent points (e.g., 2.5 and 5 units for 2 points on a line of length 10)? Please expand your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do, and what you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Your goal is to find the "best" parameters `a` and `b` such that your points k=0,1,...,n can be placed at position `a * k + b` along the line (where 0 is one extremity of the line and L is the other extremity). Choose a and b to best represent what you want. Your question is too vague for anyone else to choose for you.

Comment: What output would you expect for length of 10 and 3 points, and why? Length of 10 and 7 points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you got line given its 2 endpoints `p0,p1` and number of points `n` which are to be placed evenly on interior of the line where gap between those points and endpoit s is half of the avg distance between points ...

For floating point values linear interpolation will give you the points:

```
p(t) = p0 + (p1-p0)*t
```

where `t = <0.0,1.0>` will give you any point along line parametrized by `t`. Now its just a matter to compute `t` so:

```
dt = |p1-p0| / n
t = 0.5*dt + i*dt
i = { 0,1,2,3, ... ,n-1 }
```

Once integer values are involved you can truncate/round the resulting position into integers or use line rasterization algorithms like DDA or Bresenham for this where you can add another axis with difference equal to `2+2*n` and use only every even points with that axis coordinate change.

Comment: Thanks @Spektre. Just one more thig. Maybe this sounds strange, but anyways. Where can I learn thigs like this? I mean, I'm lost whenever I face problems like this, and I feel like I would come up with a solution (as you've done) if I had a mathematical background, so, is this college level maths, or what should I study in order to be able (like you), to solve this problems?

Comment: @ArnauMas `vector math + algebra + linear algebra + low level graphics` knowledge usually get you  huge boost in programming problems to solve things easily and efficient. some of the knowledge can be gained in secondary school and some in college. However you still need to practice programming a lot in order to achieve better understanding and performance. And not everyone have brain cells for this kind of work ...